# Why in ruby, 0.692 * 3 = 2.0759999999999996?

Tags: ruby

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]

$ irb
irb(main):001:0> 0.692 * 3
=> 2.0759999999999996
```

I just ran into these numbers by chance. Is this related to [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)?.

Comment: Yes, it is related to that.

Comment: Yep, and same in any other language (e.g. Python, Java,...) that uses the same floating point standard.

Comment: Because of [IEEE-754 floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point).

Answer (score 1):

Because floats are inaccurate, for arbitrary precision arithmetic in Ruby you can use [`BigDecimal`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html):

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/util'

("0.692".to_d * 3).to_s('F')
=> "2.076"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `BigDecimal` from the standard library will work for this, but we can solve this problem by using `round` function -

```
 (0.692 * 3).round(2) = 2.08
```